# Obtaining the parameters of the winform form (Width & height)

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want to obtain the height and width properties of a winforms form to be able to color all of it?

I've tried this code..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Rectangle r=this.DisplayRectangle;
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(0, 0, r.X, r.Y));
    }
}
```

But it doesn't do the job. How do I color the whole form in black with the graphics object and Rectangle object?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit as it doesn't seem to make any sense. If you're asking someone for clarification on their answer, *do so as a comment on their answer*. If you really need to make a substantial change to your original question, post it as an "Update", i.e. leave the existing question text as-is and add new below. This will help others understand the question in context. Also, perhaps you could try a bit harder with the formatting you use - it'll make it a lot easier for people to answer your question =)

Comment: Sorry , Robs, after i modified my algorithm by the answer provided, i considered this question as solved..so i posted the solution, and replaced it with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do like that, you will just be painting on the screen where the window happens to be. The window is not aware of that, and when the window is updated for any reason it will be redrawn without the color.

Use the `Paint` event to draw graphics on the window. Add an event handler for the event, and it will be called whenever the window has to be redrawn. The event arguments contains a `Graphics` object that you should use for drawing.

Use the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `DisplayRectangle` as width and height, not the `X` and `Y` properties. However, as the `Graphics` object is clipped to the area that is to be updated, you could just use the `Clear` method to fill it with a color.

Answer (score 1):

I have two buttons on my form(in design view) `button1_Click` is to paint it black, and `button2_Click` is to paint form back to Control color.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Brush brushToPaint;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        brushToPaint = SystemBrushes.Control;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brushToPaint, this.DisplayRectangle);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brushToPaint = Brushes.Black;
        InvokePaint(this, new PaintEventArgs(this.CreateGraphics(), this.DisplayRectangle));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        brushToPaint = SystemBrushes.Control;
        InvokePaint(this, new PaintEventArgs(this.CreateGraphics(), this.DisplayRectangle));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i didnt know that algorithm..what does this do SystemBrushes.Control;

Comment: Check [SystemBrushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systembrushes.aspx) on MSDN, simply put they are predfined colored brushes, used by Windows itself. like Control color, Highlight color, inactive window color etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to do this using `Graphics` and `DisplayRectangle`?

The form has a property called [BackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktb99cf2.aspx), which you could simply set to black:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```